# Mass shift in QED: perturbative mass terms

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, fermions

This question is similar to [Peskin & Schroeder Chap. 7.1 ultraviolet divergence](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/572987/), but my doubt is still unsolved so let me ask the question.

The Peskin & Schroeder explains on p. 221 why the mass shift in QED becomes proportional to bare mass, as

> "Suppose that $m_0$ were set to 0. Then the two helicity components of the electron field $\psi_L$ and $\psi_R$ would not be coupled by any term in the QED Hamiltonian. This would imply that perturbative corrections could never induce a coupling of $\psi_L$ and $\psi_R$, nor, in particular, an electron mass term."

However, I don't understand why they wrote "$m_0 = 0$ gives no mass terms in perturbative expansion".

Indeed, due to $m_0 = 0$ the Dirac mass term in the tree-level Lagrangian vanishes.

However, for the scalar field theory, the two-point function is given by
\begin{align}
<0| T\phi(x)\phi(y) \exp \left\{ (-i) \int H_I (t) dt \right\} |0>,
\end{align}
where $H_I$ is an interaction Hamiltonian in the interaction picture.

For QED, the interaction Hamiltonian $H_I$ does not contain $\psi_L^\dagger \psi_R$ coupling *ab initio*.

Thus, I think, in the perturbative expansion $$\exp \left\{ (-i) \int H_I (t) dt \right\} = \sum_{n=0} \frac{1}{n!}(-i H_I)^n$$ itself, $m_0=0$ has nothing to do with generating couplings with different chirality.

Where is my misunderstanding point?

I wonder if I need to expand $\psi_{L, R}(x)$ in terms of creation/annihilation operators when $m_0 = 0$ to understand the statement.

Comment: You have to write all the terms out using $\psi_L,\ \psi_R$ and see that, if $m_0=0$, then chirality is an exact local and global symmetry of the entire system. There is then no way for any perturbation, which also obeys the symmetry, to generate a this mixing, i.e. no mass perturbation.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Thanks, but my question is different from that point. Exactly for the case of $m_0 = 0$, the symmetry forbids the mass terms. However, QED interaction part does NOT contain $\psi_L ^\dagger \psi_R$ coupling, but does $\psi_L^\dagger \bar{\sigma} \psi_R$. So I guess from the beginning, there is no generation of $\psi_L^\dagger \psi_R$ (times $A_\mu$) couplings at any vertices.

Comment: In other words, I don't find any vertices consisting of $(\psi_L, \psi_R, A_\mu)$ even for $m_0 > 0$ case, in the QED interaction Hamiltonian $H_I = \int d^3 x e \bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \psi A_\mu$.

Comment: In the above comment, I made a mistake. The correct term which the QED interaction part contains is $\psi^\dagger_L \bar{\sigma} \psi_L$.

Comment: The point is that, if there was a mass term, then the perturbation could use the existing mass term to modify the mass term. Which is why the text is worded as it is.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Thank you. Hmm.... So, in the correlation function, $<\Omega|T{\psi(x) \bar{\psi(y)}}|\Omega> \propto <0|T \psi(x) \bar{\psi(y)} \exp((-i) \int dt H_I(t)) |0>$, the first $\psi(x), \bar{\psi(y)}$ outside the exponential generates mass correction? Because, $H_I$ does not depend of $m_0$.  The Wick contraction between $\psi, \bar{\psi}$ gives the free propagator of the Dirac field. Then, although I have not checked, for the $m_0=0$ Weyl fermions, the (Feynman) propagator between $<0| \psi_L \bar{\psi}_R|0>$ has to be zero? Then the mass correction will be zero.

Comment: The free propagator between Weyl fermions with different chirality will be zero, because they are decoupled at the tree-level. However, for the Dirac fermion, $<0|\psi \bar{\psi}|0>$ doesn't have such a structure (otherwise, the propagater willbe off-diagonal.), because the creation/annihilation operators mixes two chiralities (they only refer to particle/antiparticle). Thus, I wrote in the question that I need to expand Weyl fermions for the $m=0$ case. Is my understanding correct...?

Comment: Well, now I understand that the free Dirac propagator $S_F(x-y)$ becomes off-diagonal when $m=0$, as expected in the Weyl fermion system. Then the propagators which connect different chiralities are zero, so are the Wick contractions. Therefore the two-point correlation function $<\Omega| T \psi(x) \bar{\psi}(y) | \Omega> \propto <0| T \psi(x) \bar{\psi}(y) \exp(-i \int dt H_I(t))|0>$ has no chirality flip at all. However, P&S and @naturallyInconsistent said that the mass corrections could use the existing mass term. To me, it seems to be a matter of the propagator.

Comment: So, why can we conclude the existence of the mass term is the nature of the problem? Is it a chicken or egg problem?